# Isn't node.js's fs module writeFile method a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, fs

I'm developing a React App which, at some point, just for a demonstration I need to make, should save a component's state to a JSON file when a button is clicked.
The button is in a child component and has an onClick prop set to a handleChange in the parent component (whose state I want to save).
The handleChange function is as follows:

```
    handleSave(event) {
        const fs = require('fs');
        const save = (obj) => fs.writeFile('../reports/report.json', JSON.stringify(obj));

        this.setState({datetime: new Date()}, save(this.state));
    }
```

The App runs ok untill the button to save is clicked. When I click the button I get the following error:

`TypeError: fs.writeFile is not a function`

I'm new to React and not very experienced with Node/JS. Can anyone explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: Are you attempting to use `fs` in the browser? You can't—browser environments don't have access to the filesystem like pure Node environments do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing React, javascript and Node. While the language (javascript) is the same, React is used to build frontend and Node for backend.
In this case the react application should call an api that saves the file to the filesystem using node on the backend.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Although I "know" the difference, this sort of detail still confuse me. Thanks.